# Power plan override?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power-management

Anybody know of a program that can detect if you're viewing a video, and if you are, prevent the current power plan from turning off the monitor and/or putting the computer to sleep?

(For Windows 7, or one for Vista might also work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some video players can disable those without extra tools. I think VLC is capable to do so and perhaps Windows Media Player too.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that you can set the power management to prevent the computer to go to sleep directrly in the power management console in Windows 7 itself.

Go in Customise your desktop and at the bottom right end corner, go to wallpaper and then, change your power settings. It might be as simple as that.

Comment: The question is for automation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that...